# What is for the Index option in TRemotable derivated classes?

Tags: delphi, class, soap, interface

When WSDL importer wizard generates the interfaces, all properties have the Index option, but reading the code and the InvokeRegistry unit, I can't found what is that for, anyone know if it is really necessary?

Like this

```
  Login = class(TRemotable)
  private
    [...] 
  published
    property User: string Index (IS_OPTN) read GetUser write SetUser stored User_Specified;
    [...]
  end;
```

I'm asking because I want to change this unit, adding some Interfaces to this classes, for integrate with MVP framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a more detailed explanation for this question, 
**When using Indexes, several properties can share the same access methods.**

A good example, from Delphi 2009 Help:

```
type 
   TRectangle = class 
     private 
       FCoordinates: array[0..3] of Longint; 
       function GetCoordinate(Index: Integer): Longint; 
       procedure SetCoordinate(Index: Integer; Value: Longint); 
     public 
       property Left: Longint index 0 read GetCoordinate write SetCoordinate; 
       property Top: Longint index 1 read GetCoordinate write SetCoordinate; 
       property Right: Longint index 2 read GetCoordinate write SetCoordinate; 
       property Bottom: Longint index 3 read GetCoordinate write SetCoordinate; 
       property Coordinates[Index: Integer]: Longint read GetCoordinate write SetCoordinate; 
       ... 
   end;
```

Note, all properties shares the same method access.

Answer (score 2):

IS_OPTN is passed to GetUser and SetUser via the 'Index' parameter when you access the user property.

The getters/setters probably look like this:

```
function GetUser(Index:Integer):String;
procedure SetUser(Index:Integer;const value:string);
```

So, think of it as this:

```
MyString := MyLogin.user;
// is translated to:
MyString := getUser(IS_OPTN);
```

and

```
MyLogin.user := 'me'; 
// is translated to:
SetUser(IS_OPTN,'me');
```

Comment: Wouter, It is like that, but the parameter is not used inside any method, that why my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary. With this information, for exemple IS_OPTN, the class from TRemotable knows that when property is Optional to build XML, so if is optional, the node is added only if the value is stored. On your case:

```
property User: string Index (IS_OPTN) read GetUser write SetUser stored User_Specified
```

The element *User* will be added on XML if *User_Specified* true. The *User_Specified* turns automatically true when you set value to User, because the setter SetUser do it.

So, when the component SOAP por example, will build the XML, the element will be added only if is stored because it is Optional (IS_OPTN).